# WiX Bootstrapper Package execution

Tags: wix, wix-extension

Is there any way to get the count/details of packages that will be be actually executed, i.e details such as "Detected package: state = present/absent"? This information is available in the logs, but I would like to get this information in my bootstrapper before the execution of packages is initiated or soon after the DetectComplete event.
BootstrapperApplicationData.xml does not hold this info :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the detection and plan information by responding to events in the BA, such as `DetectPackageComplete` and `PlanPackageComplete`. The `EventArgs` arguments contain additional properties like `PackageId` and `State`.

Comment: Yes,I could use the DetectPackageComplete event to gather the information required. Thank you very much.